# Decile Pandas DataFrame on column

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, statistics, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Pandas that I would like to decile on a specific column and then get the means for each of these deciles.

Here is the data set:

[image]

I am looking to decile the res column and maintain the ticker column as well as the rest of the data inegrity and the get the mean across each of the deciles.

I was attempting to use `pd.qcut(beta.res,10)` but could not reorganize the data using the results from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use the fact that [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) returns something that you can use for `groupby`, so it would simply be something like:

```
 df.groupby(pd.qcut(beta.res,10)).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 10], [3, 100], [4, 100]]),
                  columns=['a', 'b'])

df.quantile(.1)
a    1.3
b    3.7
Name: 0.1, dtype: float64

df.quantile([.1, .5])
       a     b
0.1  1.3   3.7
0.5  2.5  55.0
```